# What's the quickest Agility Course in RS3?

Tags: runescape

There are many agility courses scattered around in Runescape 3, What's the shortest one? I have not explored anything more than Burthrope Agility course.

Quickest for Yak Track.

Comment: Quickest, or best XP an hour? You may want to clarify that in your title/question.

Comment: @TimmyJim Quickest!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the wiki, the shortest agility course by time is the [Barbarian Outpost Agility Course](https://runescape.wiki/w/Barbarian_Outpost_Agility_Course) with an approximate lap time of 30 seconds. The [Bandos Agility Course](https://runescape.wiki/w/Bandos_Agility_Course) is a close second, with an approximate lap time of 35 seconds.